# Returning Two graphs using a single function in r

Tags: r, plot

i am trying to implement a function to plot two time series plots using a single function but it returns only one here is code what is wrong with it

```
visualize <- function(x) {

    x<-data.frame(x)

    x1 <- x[x$chr == 1, ]
    x2 <- x[x$chr != 1, ]

    t1<-data.frame("range"=1:nrow(x1))
    t2<-data.frame("range"=1:nrow(x2))

    t1$testsample_first<-exp(x1$testSample1)
    t1$testsample_second<-exp(x1$testSample2)


    t2$testsample_first<-exp(x2$testSample1)
    t2$testsample_second<-exp(x2$testSample2)

    dygraph(t1);dygraph(t2)
 }


(visualize(scon))
```

It is plotting second one only .I tried to implement by calling a second function in first but same result.

Comment: If you want to return multiple objects, return list

Comment: #1 Please provide a reproducible example including dummy data and the required libraries, ready to copy-paste-run. #2 It's probably potting the 1st and the 2nd, but the 2nd is replacing the 1st. If you are using RStudio, you can use the back button in the viewer pane.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to return the two objects together in a `list`:

```
list(plot(t1), plot(t2))
```

Comment: Severin Pappadeu Thanxs it worked My mistake was i was using  return and it was returning vector matrix .